# Arrangement within `\langle \rangle`

Tags: formatting

I have a group defined in algebra as such in my MWE. The problem is that it is too long to fit in one line. How can I make it look better?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$$G = \langle a, b, x, y, z \;|\; a^4 = 1_G =1, b^2 =1, ab=ba, x^3=y^3=z^3=1, xy=yx, x^a = xy, x^b =x, y^a =xy^2, y^b =y, z^a =xyz, z^b = y^2z^2[y,z], [x, y, x]=1 \rangle$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a code adapted from the code for the set-builder notation described in the documentation of `mathtools`, nested in a `medsize` environment from `nccmath`; in order to make it fit in two lines.

I define a  `\GenRels` command, with *one* argument in two parts: the generators and the relations, separated by a `\st` command. The size of the delimiters and the vertical rule adapts automatically to the size of the content if you use the star version of the command, which add implicit `\left \middle \right` at the relevant places. Alternatively, you can fine-tune the size of the delimiters using as an optional argument one of `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3cm, vmargin=3cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\providecommand\st{}
\newcommand\RelSymbol[1][]{%
\nonscript\:#1\vert
\allowbreak
\nonscript\:
\mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\GenRels[1]\langle\rangle{%
\renewcommand\st{\RelSymbol[\delimsize]}
#1}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\[ \GenRels*{ a, b, x, y, z \st
\begin{medsize}
\begin{aligned} & a^4 = 1_G =1,\enspace b^2 =1, \enspace ab=ba, \enspace x^3=y^3=z^3=1, \enspace xy=yx,\enspace x^a = xy, \\[-0.5ex] %
 & x^b =x, \enspace y^a =xy^2,\enspace y^b =y,\enspace z^a =xyz,\enspace z^b = y^2z^2[y,z],\enspace [x, y, x]=1%
\end{aligned}
\end{medsize}
} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could put the thing in a multi-lined `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
G ={}& \langle a, b, x, y, z \;|\; a^4 = 1_G =1, b^2 =1, ab=ba, x^3=y^3=z^3=1,\\
&xy=yx, x^a = xy, x^b =x, y^a =xy^2, y^b =y, z^a =xyz, z^b = y^2z^2[y,z],\\
& [x, y, x]=1 \rangle
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an internal `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
G = \langle a, b, x, y, z \mid
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  & a^4 = 1_G =1, b^2 =1, ab=ba,\\
  & x^3=y^3=z^3=1, xy=yx, \\
  & x^a = xy, x^b =x, \\
  & y^a =xy^2, y^b =y, \\
  & z^a =xyz, z^b = y^2z^2[y,z], \\
  & [x, y, x]=1 \rangle
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I grouped the identities “by kind”.

An important note: never use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

[image]